# Which is the better structure, passing an event handler as an arg, or listening to the event firing?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm wondering about the appropriate class structure regarding the usage of an event handler.

I have Age class, which causes action when the age value is changed. I have a Person class, which has an Age object as its member variable.

In my first scenario, Person class passes its event handler to the Age object as an arg of its constructor.

```
class Age
{
    private readonly EventHandler _valueChanged;

    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        private set
        {
            _value = value;
            RaiseValueChangedEvent();
        }
    }

    public Age(EventHandler handler)
    {
        _valueChanged = handler;
    }

    protected void RaiseValueChangedEvent()
    {
        var handler = _valueChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    private readonly Age _age;

    public Person()
    {
        _age = new Age(OnAgeChanged);
    }

    protected void OnAgeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what is necessary.
    }
}
```

In my second scenario, Age class has an event and Person class listens to its event firing.

```
class Age
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        private set
        {
            _value = value;
            RaiseValueChangedEvent();
        }
    }

    protected void RaiseValueChangedEvent()
    {
        var handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    private readonly Age _age = new Age();

    public Person()
    {
        _age.ValueChanged += OnAgeChanged;
    }

    protected void OnAgeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do what is necessary.
    }
}
```

Which is the better structure? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's point out a few things here:

- An `event` is a *multicast delegate* that allows to broadcast messages to signal the occurrence of an action
- A `delegate` is a type that represents references to methods using which we can invoke them

So both of approaches shown here are 'correct' in some scenarios and 'incorrect' in others. If all we want is to execute a callback method then it's sufficient to pass a delegate.

However if we want to implement producer->consumer pattern or any other event-based patterns then we would need an `event` there.

P.S.
Here is an amazing [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) by Jon Skeet where he explains in details what is the difference between events and delegates

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I totally forgot that an event is a multicast delegate. I decided to choose the second approach since it makes it easier to invoke multiple action when the `Value` of `Age` changes.

Comment: @user4134476 Btw I've added a link to an amazing article written by Jon Skeet that you might want to look into

Comment: Thank you again for your kindness. The article helped me a lot to understand the difference between an event and a delegate.